# SQL: creating Dynamic SQL getting scalar error on XML node

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I'm getting an error

> Must declare the scalar variable "@model_look_xml"

when creating a dynamic query.

This executes fine:

```
SELECT * 
FROM model 
WHERE (model_height BETWEEN 0.00 AND 80.00 
  AND model_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT assn.assn_model_id 
                   FROM model_look 
                   INNER JOIN model_skill ON model_look.model_look_model_id =
model_skill.model_skill_model_id 
                   INNER JOIN assn ON assn.assn_model_id = model_skill.model_skill_model_id
                   WHERE assn.assn_office = 34 
                     AND model_skill_skill_id = 12 
                     AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                                 FROM @model_look_xml.nodes('/root/id') AS result(node) 
                                 WHERE node.value('(.)[1]', 'int') = model_look_look_id))
```

When I try to break it up dynamically, I'm not sure how to handle the nodes.

This works fine:

```
declare @model_look_xml xml
declare @model_skill_xml xml
declare @model_eyes_xml xml
declare @model_hair_xml xml
declare @model_ethnicity_xml xml
declare @model_skill_skill_id int
declare @assn_office int
declare @top_height decimal(4,2)
declare @low_height decimal(4,2)
declare @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
--testing values
set @assn_office = 34
set @top_height  = 80.00
set @low_height  = 0.00
set @model_look_xml = CAST('<root><id>7</id><id>6</id><id>12</id></root>' AS XML)

SET @SQL = N'SELECT * FROM model where '
SET @SQL = @SQL + N'(model_height between '
SET @SQL = @SQL + cast(@low_height as varchar(50)) 
SET @SQL = @SQL + ' and '
SET @SQL = @SQL + cast(@top_height as varchar(50))
SET @SQL = @SQL + N' and model_id in (Select distinct assn.assn_model_id From '
SET @SQL = @SQL + N'model_look Inner Join
    model_skill On model_look.model_look_model_id =
    model_skill.model_skill_model_id Inner Join
    assn On assn.assn_model_id = model_skill.model_skill_model_id
    Where assn.assn_office = '+ cast(@assn_office as varchar(50)) +'
    and   model_skill_skill_id =  '+ cast(@model_skill_skill_id as varchar(50) ) --+'))'
SET @SQL = @SQL + N' and  exists(select 1 from '
```

Until I get to this line, not sure how to handle it.  If I was only going to do this once I would have found a different way, but I'm going to have 6 optional parameters(possible lists) coming in.

```
 SET @SQL = @SQL + N'@model_look_xml.nodes(''/root/id'')as result(node) where node.value(''(.)[1]'', ''int'') = model_look_look_id))'
```

Comment: @model_look_xml is not declared at any point.  For that matter, its not declared in the first example so that cant work either!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never show us where `@model_look_xm` is actually declared.  I assume it must be because you state it actually works.  However, the most likely issue is your local variable is not accessible in your dynamic sql statement.  You have to pass it as a parameter if order for you to access it.

To solve simply define `@model_look_xm` as a input parameter on your dynamic statement.

```
EXECUTE sp_executeql @SQL, N'@model_look_xm XML', @model_look_xm = @model_look_xm
```

This line is a little of an assumption because you are not showing all of your code so adjust as needed.

Comment: Thanks Matt, that fixed it!